# how to use ref in multi-step registration in react es6?

Tags: reactjs, refs

I'm trying to develop multistep registration, referring this link : https://www.viget.com/articles/building-a-multi-step-registration-form-with-react

But I could not use refs and don't know how to fix this.

This is the error msg I get everytime I click on 'next' button
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQgnM.png)

and this is my code

```
              <input type="text"
                     className='singleComponent'
                     name='AppName'
                     ref='AppName'
                     defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.AppName }
                     />

            <button>Cancel</button>
            <button onClick={this.SaveAndContinue}>Next</button>


  SaveAndContinue(e){
      e.preventDefault();

    var data={
        AppName : this.refs.AppName,
  }

    this.props.saveValues(data)
    this.props.nextStep()
  }

  }
```

Dependencies :

```
"react": "^16.1.0",
"react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
"react-dom": "^16.1.0",
```

can someone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the exact cause of the issues you are seeing, it is recommended that you update from your implementation which uses string refs to a callback version.

So instead of:
`ref='AppName'`

Use:
`ref={(input) => { this.AppName = input; }}`

Then you will access the reference the element within `AddApplicationField` via:
`this.AppName`

This may solve your issue since there are known issues with the legacy string ref method.

See more here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by modifying button to :

```
    <button onClick={this.SaveAndContinue.bind(this)}>Next</button>
```